# How can I run Go binary files?

Tags: go

I read a lot about "You can run a Go program from binaries without even having Go installed on your machine", etc. How exactly should I execute the app?

In my case I have a console application which sends emails if a certain event occurs. There also is a .toml file for configuring it. How should I run the app on a PC which does not have Go installed and is running [Ubuntu 14.04.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) 64-bit OS?

Comment: it's like running any binary file... make it executable `chmod +x` and run it `./binary`

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the problem was lack of Ubintu knowledge :)

Answer (score 30):

The application should be executed just like any other binary can be executed in the given OS. In your case, running on Ubuntu, you must first compile the application for that particular architecture:

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build
```

Then you can modify the permissions of the binary to be executable:

```
chmod +x my-app
```

And simply execute it:

```
./my-app
```

Answer (score 10):

To avoid using `./` or any other path to the binary, you can copy the binary file to your `/usr/local/bin/` path.

For example-

1. Download a binary file that was compiled with Go, for example `app`
2. Provide execution permission - `chmod +x ~/Downloads/app`
3. Copy binary file to `/usr/local/bin` - `cp ~/Downloads/app /usr/local/bin/app`
4. Execute the application from anywhere - `app`

Comment: Thanks, I installed some modules they were  `/Users/user/go/bin` directory, each time I needed to move to that directory for execution, I have forgotten about coping binary to `/usr/local/bin` your answer remained me, thanks for your help!)